# Cakephp - change baked files default directory

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bake

By default doing cake bake the files are placed in directory according to cake conventions. E.g. when baking views for `PostsController` my `add, edit, index` and `view` files will be under `app/View/Posts`. Instead of that I want to have all my actions in `AdminsController` and all the folders - inside `app/View/Admins/` folder, like `app/View/Admins/Posts` and it will contain the files for posts. I could perhaps make usual bake and then move the files and folders, but is there a way that I achieve this programmatically ?

cake v 2.x

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those to need to achieve what I wanted , take a look at `bake` function of this file `\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ViewTask.php`